# how to filter an output json from a database connector using transform message in mule3

Tags: json, mule

I am currently working on a issue, where i am facing issue while filtering the json data from
output json using transform messge in mule 3.

output json

```
{
  "BOOKING": 0.0,
  "SRP_GOAL_HEADER_ID": 3041920
},
{
  "BOOKING": 0.0,
  "SRP_GOAL_HEADER_ID": 3041920
},
{
  "BOOKING": 10.0,
  "SRP_GOAL_HEADER_ID": 3041920
}
```

I would like to filter this json so that i should only get  the below as the output.

```
{
  "BOOKING": 10.0,
  "SRP_GOAL_HEADER_ID": 3041920
}
```

Appreciate someone Help

Thank, 
Nikhil

Comment: What is the filter definition? Is the database returning JSON? By default records are returned as Java objects. Note that your JSON is invalid, it looks like an array but the braces are missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter operator of DataWeave 1.0. If the criteria for filtering is that the BOOKING attribute is greater than 0, then you use like this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload filter ($.BOOKING > 0)
```

Input:

```
[ { "BOOKING": 0.0, "SRP_GOAL_HEADER_ID": 3041920 }, { "BOOKING": 0.0, "SRP_GOAL_HEADER_ID": 3041920 }, { "BOOKING": 10.0, "SRP_GOAL_HEADER_ID": 3041920 }]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "BOOKING": 10.0,
    "SRP_GOAL_HEADER_ID": 3041920
  }
]
```